# Laptop adapter turns on and off while hanging my Ubuntu system?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery, adapter

My laptop charger when plugged to my laptop keeps turning on and off and while this happens my laptop hangs badly and I cant do any work but when i unplug the adapter the laptop works perfectly fine. So the only workaround i found was turning off my laptop and charging and then use it on battery but that stays for around 1.30 hrs and my laptop battery discharges by that time. I need an urgent project to be completed so this is not helping me in any way :(

PS: The main issue i know could be is like i plugged my laptop charger to an extension but that extension had a short and fused that might have caused the problem. So just wanted to know if it is my laptop or charger the issue with? Due to current situation it is kinda difficult for me arrange a new charger if any help or workaround suggestion would be really really helpful.Thanks !

Comment: Try a different charger. It is most likely the charger, but it also could be a loose connection at the entry point to the laptop or an error in the charging circuit. You may wish to visit a shop and have them tell you more accurately where the problem is.

Comment: As @John states, most likely a loose connection. 1. Watch the charging light on the laptop while wiggling the cable(s) and extension cord in various spots, and look for it to blink. 2. Tape the cords down to the table and laptop to prevent future wiggles.

Comment: Hey it was my issue with the adapter like i somehow arranged a spare charger and it works but there's one issue with that charger like the output Amp:2.25 while my original one had 3.25A while output voltage is same 20V hope this wont be an issue for the time being.